# How to implement pure virtual functions with different parameter structures

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual, abstract, pure-virtual

I'm building a class with pure virtual functions called `Database`. The idea is to have a class that handles all the database interfaces (ie: `open` and `close`) and can be used on my business layers.

The Database class will be implemented in several 'flavours' for different databases, like mySqlDatabase and OracleDatabase.

I imagined `Database` having pure virtual methods with no code - just a header file as follows:

**Database.hpp**

```
class Database {

    public:
        Database();
        virtual ~Database();

        virtual void open(const std::string databasename) = 0;
        virtual void open(const std::string databasename, const std::string username, const std::string password) = 0;
        virtual void open(const std::string databasename, const std::string schema, const std::string username, const std::string password) = 0;

.
<Other stuff>
.

}
```

The three `open` variations are there to support different database connection requirements, from the simplest one (like Sqlite3 that needs only a filename), to Oracle (that needs all of that variables to connect).

I have some questions about the implementations (let's take oracle for example):

a) Shall I need to redeclare the virtual methods again on the derived class header file, like:

```
    class  OracleDatabase : public Database {

    public:
        OracleDatabase ();
        virtual ~OracleDatabase ();

        void open(const std::string databasename);
        void open(const std::string databasename, const std::string username, const std::string password);
        void open(const std::string databasename, const std::string schema, const std::string username, const std::string password);
}
```

b) How do I structure the implementation of the `open` methods in the derived class (let´s take Sqlite3)?

```
void Sqlite3Database::open(const std::string databasename){
          ...do some stuff...
}

void Sqlite3Database::open(const std::string databasename, const std::string username, const std::string password) {
          ...do some stuff...
    }

void Sqlite3Database::open(const std::string databasename, const std::string schema, const std::string username, const std::string password) {
          ...do some stuff...
    }
```

Am I using the right strategy? I've been browsing around virtual and pure virtual strategies and think this is the best approach for my problem.

Any suggestions/hints?

OBS: I'm coming from C# world so I do apologize if there is some misconception here.

Comment: Have you looked into the interface based design pattern? http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns#Interface-based_Programming_.28IBP.29

Comment: I´m familiar with the interface design pattern.. I´ve used it already in C# and is what i want to accomplish... My doubts are related to C++ syntax and behaviour on how to implement it, specially having different 'open' methods...

Comment: I would recommend marking your member functions as `override` in the subclass, as in: `void open(const std::string databasename) override;`  This will ensure you get a compiler error if you aren't actually overriding anything.

Comment: Further, things like "open"/"close" and "require"/"release" are better left to RAII in C++

Comment: Ryan, when you say 'RAII in C++' you mean opening the db on constructor and releasing on destructor avoiding the open/close methods ?

Comment: @Mendez: That's what RAII means, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For writing query functions (ie. same interface for all databases), pure virtual functions are the way to go.

<s>Here, you are trying to write an `open` function, for which you might want to consider the [Factory Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern): you write your Database withour any `open` function; and you write a function such as `static std::unique_ptr<Database> Sqlite3Database::open(/*...*/)`.</s>

Using a virtual function like the one you are advocating is not a good idea: anyway you have 3 different functions that completely depend on the database that is used; and worse, your mother class depends on its children: to add a new database with another logging scheme, you have to add a function prototype to `Database`.

Another way to go would be to use a pure virtual function (preferably `protected` and called from constructor to preserve RAII; and following the [NVI idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface)) that takes as argument an initialization string such as the one used by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php). Not exactly the same as anyway the database type can be inferred from the type instantiated, but the idea is to keep a single argument so as not to have multiple versions of `open`

(Old answer kept for the principles it tried to explain)

Actually you can do much easier: forget about `open`, and just do all of your initialization inside `Sqlite3Database::Sqlite3Database(/* ... */)`.

After all, there is no way you can open a database without knowing which kind of DB it is (as you have to know a username/password, and even more: you have to know what arguments are required), so there is no sense in trying to make a virtual pure function out of this.

So, an example of what you could do:

```
class Database {
    public virtual void create(/* ... */) = 0;
    // ...
};

class Sqlite3Database : public Database {
    Sqlite3Database(string filename);
    public virtual void create(/* ... */) override;
    // ...
};

class MySqlDatabase : public Database {
    MySqlDatabase(int host, short port, string username, string password);
    public virtual void create(/* ... */) override;
};
```

Comment: Ekleog, I got your point... The constructor/destructor idea makes sense.. I just don´t wanna use PDOs as it will be confusing for the above sw layers... I´m thinking of building different constructors requiring the exact parameters for the implemented db type...

Comment: I've just add an example of what exactly I mean by this. This is not using PDO.